# Why the shell knows the interpreter specified in the shebang-line of a file without read permission

Tags: unix, permissions, filesystems, interpreter, shebang

I am trying to learn shell on Linux,
but I've got a problem which seems confusing.

- My environment is:

  - OS: Manjaro 21.2.6 Qonos
  - Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.38-1-MANJARO
  - Shell: zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- The problem is:

  - I created a file named `foo`, and echoed `#\!/bin/sh` to it, and the permission of file `foo` has been modified to `100` by using `chmod`.
  - The file `foo` doesn't have the read or write permission indeed, that's for true,
  - but when I executed the command `./foo`, I got the error `/bin/sh: ./foo: permission denied`.

*So why the Shell knows what the shebang in the file `foo` is without the read permission ???*

If anyone of you can proide any suggesstions, I will be really thankful !

[behavior-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltJeX.png)

Comment: You should copy&paste the exact commands you used instead of describing the commands in your text. this would reduce misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *So why the Shell knows what the shebang in the file foo is without the read permission ???*

It is not the shell that reads the shebang line but the OS/kernel.

A shell script can be executed in the same way as a compiled program. The process uses a function of the `exec*` family and passes `./foo` as the program to execute. These functions are based on system calls.

The OS/kernel then detects if the file is a compiled program which can be executed directly or a script file which must be passed to an interpreter. If the file contains a shebang line, the OS will execute the *specified* interpreter, which does not have to be a shell, otherwise it will run the default shell. The script file is passed as an argument to the interpreter.

The shell is running with normal user permissions and will get an error when it tries to open the script file.

---

You can find some information about executiong scripts in the [POSIX specification of the `exec` function family](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) or in the [Linux manual page for `execve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Search for the word *interpreter*. You could check the Linux kernel source code for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot ! btw, does your explanation have relevant documents? Like Wikipedia? I want to get more information !

Comment: @Lpj I added references to documentation/specification.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the script itself do not have execution or **read permission**. To run script in shell (on your way) you need to have read and execute permissions:

```
chmod 500 foo
./foo
```

the other way to run the script is:

```
sh foo
```

and you do not need execution permission in this case. For the record the standard way is to use construction like:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

You do not need to escape exclamation mark

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understand what you said, but firstly escape exclamation mark is needed because I was run the command `echo "#\!/bin/sh" > a_blank_file` in the shell prompt, besides, my question is 「why the Shell knows that I wrote `#\!/bin/sh` to the file without the read permission ？」

Comment: @Lpj, edited answer and add in bold the reason.

Comment: what's the meaning ? sorry but i am learning endlish :)

Comment: @Lpj, the text i enter in **black**

Comment: okay, got your words, I will be careful in the next time, thanks a lot !